# Como converter um algoritimo recursivo para iterativo, estou sem saber como fazer essa conversão, qualquer ajudar é bem vinda!

Tags: c++, loop, estrutura-de-dados, recursão, iterator

Algoritimo 1

```
void pre_ordem(struct arvore *f) {
    if(f == NULL) { 
        return; 
 }
     printf("%d", f->dado);
     pre_ordem(f->esq);
     pre_ordem(f->dir);
} // pre ordem
```

Algoritimo 2

```
void ordem_central(struct arvore *f) {
    if(f == NULL) {
       return; 
   }
     ordem_central(f->esq);
     printf("%d", f->dado);
     ordem_central(f->dir);
} //central
```

Algoritimo 3

```
void pos_ordem(struct arvore *f) {
if(f == NULL) {
    return; 
 }
   pos_ordem (f->esq);
   pos_ordem (f->dir);
   printf("%d", f->dado);
} //pós ordem
```

Answer (score -1):

Com C++ podemos usar uma stack e inserir os nódulos para iterar sobre eles.

```
#include <stack>

void pre_ordem_iterativo(struct arvore* f) {
    std::stack<arvore*> stack;
    stack.push(f);

    while (!stack.empty())
    {
        auto* node = stack.top();
        stack.pop();

        printf(" %d ", node->dado);

        if (node->dir)
        {
            stack.push(node->dir);
        }
        if (node->esq)
        {
            stack.push(node->esq);
        }
    }
}

void ordem_central_iterativo(struct arvore* f) {
    std::stack<arvore*> stack;
    auto* curr = f;

    while (!stack.empty() || curr)
    {
        if (curr)
        {
            stack.push(curr);
            curr = curr->esq;
        }
        else
        {
            curr = stack.top();
            stack.pop();

            printf(" %d ", curr->dado);

            curr = curr->dir;
        }
    }
}

void pos_ordem_iterativo(struct arvore* f) {
    std::stack<arvore*> stack, out_stack;
    stack.push(f);

    while (!stack.empty())
    {
        auto* node = stack.top();
        stack.pop();

        out_stack.push(node);

        if (node->esq)
        {
            stack.push(node->esq);
        }
        if (node->dir)
        {
            stack.push(node->dir);
        }
    }

    while (!out_stack.empty())
    {
        auto* node = out_stack.top();
        out_stack.pop();

        printf(" %d ", node->dado);
    }
}
```